# php exec() doesn't work with PredictionIO deploy

Tags: php, linux, shell, command-line, predictionio

I am using PredictionIO for recommendation, now i want to run deploy automatic, and i use

```
  exec('cd /home/abc/sites/BeeketingEngineShop/ && /home/abc/PredictionIO/bin/pio deploy)
```

But it keep running, and doesn't deploy in 0.0.0.0:8000

When i copy

```
cd /home/abc/sites/BeeketingEngineShop/ && /home/abc/PredictionIO/bin/pio deploy
```

to terminal, it works very well

Answer (score 0):

In summary, `$HOME` was not set when using PHP's `exec()`, causing a wrong base path to be set. A detail answer could be found at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/predictionio-user/_1Hq2jMiDn4